# matching a non-boundary word

Tags: regex, grep

I am stumped with the concept of non boundary word since grep command is not returning what I would expect it to return. I am looking for lines that match only *malloc* word and not *lmmmalloc*, so I decided to use:

```
grep -inr '\bmalloc\b' .
```

which returned the following:

```
./xxxx.xx:918:    /* Free the malloc before exiting the function. */
```

After modifying the grep command to retrieve all lines that contain *lmmmalloc* using the following command:

```
grep -inr '\Bmalloc\B' .
```

I expected \B to return lines that contain  the substring *malloc*, instead of the same result as posted earlier. I hoped the result would be same as follows:

```
grep -inr '\blmmmalloc\b' 
./xxxx.xx:376:  string_temp = (char *) lmmmalloc (cxp,
```

Is my understanding flawed, if so, could somebody please clarify and rectify the grep command?

I am using GNU grep 2.5.1.

Comment: I'm running OSX (so BSD grep), but `\B` worked for me.  Have you tried `\W`?  May not work if `malloc` is the immediate character sequence on a line, but otherwise should be equivalent-ish.  E.g., `grep -inr '\Wmalloc'

Comment: @jmar777 your grep command did work but I still don't understand why \B would not just find lines with lmmmalloc.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with grep or the differences between the GNU/BSD versions to really comment on that.  Definitely strange, as I'd expect `\B` to be supported...

Comment: The `\B` patterns [work as expected](https://ideone.com/Vj6ypr).

Answer (score 1):

`\Bmalloc\B` means the `m` must be *preceded* by a word character and the `c` must be *followed* by a word character.  If you want it to match `immmalloc`, leave the second `\b` as it was:

```
grep -inr '\Bmalloc\b' .
```

Comment: This returned the same result as grep -inr '\bmalloc\b' and did not return any lines with the string 'lmmmalloc' in them.

Comment: I don't see why.  What happens if you add the `-P` option (i.e., use Perl syntax)?

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries like this in grep:

```
grep -inr "\<malloc\>"
```

Comment: This appears to do the same thing as the command grep -inr '\bmalloc\b' . The manual pages talk about subtle difference between your symbol \< and \> and the \b version where in former matches empty string before and after the word and the later matches the empty string at the edge of the word. Do you know what the difference is between \< and \b?

Comment: As per http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html: `The GNU extensions to POSIX regular expressions add support for the \b and \B word boundaries, as described above. GNU also uses its own syntax for start-of-word and end-of-word boundaries. \< matches at the start of a word, like Tcl's \m. \> matches at the end of a word, like Tcl's \M.`